# Magento 1 make all cookies secure and HttpOnly

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, secure

Is there any way to make all the cookies to secure at a time In Magento 1

I tried the following Setting in Magento 1 configuration

System->configuration->(General) > Web > session cookie management->use HTTP Only->Yes

[image]
[image]

But still, cookies are not set to HTTPOnly

I want both attributes HttpOnly and secure should be set

Let me know if anything I can do for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Same requirement, did you able to fix this ?

Comment: only server side cookies set by php will have the httponly flag set. this flag is irrelevant for client side js cookies. all cookies should have the secure flag set.